# How to mute the flv on start up?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to work on a AS3 file with a video in it. Can someone please teach me how to have the flv muted on start up?

So far I have this script:

```
import flash.events.*;
import fl.video.*;

//-----------------
// Video control assignment
//-----------------

display.playPauseButton = skin_mc.play_btn;
display.stopButton = skin_mc.stop_btn;
display.seekBar = skin_mc.seek_bar;
display.muteButton = skin_mc.mute_btn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no actual **mute** property, [`volume`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#volume) is simply toggled between 0 and what it was prior to muting. So to have the volume "muted" on startup:

```
video.volume = 0;
```

Here's some code for a button that toggles mute on/off:

```
display.muteButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _muteToggle);
function _muteToggle(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    display.volume = display.volume == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    MovieClip(e.target).gotoAndStop(display.volume+1);
}
```

This will stop the mute button on frame 1 if it's mute and frame 2 if it's not. It will have to be a MovieClip to work, not a Button.

Comment: All I have in my script is as you see above, with only display.muteButton = skin_mc.mute_btn; referring to the volume. Is there a way to utilize that line or should i remove it all together and use some if/ else statement? If I should use if/else would you be able to teach me how to with volume?

Comment: All your code is doing is defining controls for your FLVPlayback. If you want your video to **start muted**, then add my code to the top of the block of code after your initialization of FLVPlayback (or anywhere in code if you've used import->video or the components panel.

Comment: As in...Right now when I move my mouse over the control buttons, there is a green outline (i.e. this - [link](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/4264/control.jpg)). Is there a way for me to do it with the if/else statement that would allow that green outline?

Comment: Ah, if you mean can you create your own mute button, then I can supply some code to do that for you.

Comment: OH i get it, the button I'm using is a component! My bad! (I, 1.never works with controls, 2.picking up where someone left off) Now I got the sound to turn back to 1, but the mute button seem to have lost its toggle function and the volume remains 1 when I click on the button again (even though the graphics toggles between mute and unmute) display.muteButton = skin_mc.mute_btn;

display.muteButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteClickHandler);

function muteClickHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
 display.volume = 1;
}

Comment: Actually the graphics doesn't toggle either

Comment: Give the new code a try for toggle.. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Is there a way to remove the green border around the play button so the two acts the same way?

Comment: You can create a custom play button as well, or you can double click the inbuilt one and edit the display (I think).

Comment: Yeah I think I will create a custom one. I googled but got no answer to the removing green border issue. Thanks for your help!